# Normalization of eigenvectors

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to normalize the following vector in *Mathematica* with the `Normalize` command.

$$(-1+2\cot[x]\csc[x]+2\csc[x]^2,\;2^\frac{1}{2} (1+\cos[x])\csc[x],\; 1)$$

I specified that the argument was real, but keep getting `Abs` in my answer. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: What's the problem with the [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value)?

Comment: Could you post actual _Mathematica_ code ?

Comment: Real isn't enough. For example, `Csc[x]` is `ComplexInfinity` when `x=Pi`.

Answer (score 3):

`x` being real-valued isn't enough, since some of the trig functions (like `Csc[x]`) can be infinite for finite `x` (like `x=Pi`). If you make the assumption that `x` is between 0 and `Pi`, then the expression can be simplified without the Abs[]

```
v = {-1 + 2 Cot[x] Csc[x] + 2 Csc[x] 2, 2^(1/2) (1 + Cos[x]) Csc[x], 1};
FullSimplify[Normalize[v], 0 < x < Pi]
```

[image]

It also simplifies to the same answer when `Pi < x < 2 Pi` so the problem really is at the singularity. It's easy to calculate what happens at the singularities by taking the limit as  `x->0` and `x->Pi`:

```
Limit[v, x -> 0]
{∞, ∞, 1}

Limit[v, x -> Pi]
{-∞, 0, 1}
```

Comment: So it will not simplify then if x is between 0 and $2\pi$

Comment: It also simplifies if you assume `Pi < x < 2 Pi`, so the problem really is at the singularity.